# What is difference of reduce image size using resize and transform in picasso?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm using [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for load images. I find two ways for reduct images size. What is difference of reduce image size using resize

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(imageurl)
.resize(200, 100)
.onlyScaleDown() // the image will only be resized if it's bigger than 200x100 pixels.
.into(imageViewResizeScaleDown);
```

and using transform method like this one

```
public class BitmapTransform implements Transformation {

int maxWidth;
int maxHeight;

public BitmapTransform(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
    this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
}

@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int targetWidth, targetHeight;
    double aspectRatio;

    if (source.getWidth() > source.getHeight()) {
        targetWidth = maxWidth;
        aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
        targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
    } else {
        targetHeight = maxHeight;
        aspectRatio = (double) source.getWidth() / (double) source.getHeight();
        targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * aspectRatio);
    }

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
    if (result != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public String key() {
    return maxWidth + "x" + maxHeight;
}
```

};

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageurl)
                    .transform(new BitmapTransform (200, 100))
                    .into(imageViewResizeScaleDown);
```

Tanks for your help

Comment: Transforms are usually used for converting the bitmap for example to circular one etc. I think that's the real difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `resize()` is used literally for resizing the image while a `Transformation` is an interface for your image manipulation. e.g. Making the image Grayscale etc. Although you can use it also for resizing the image but the purpose isn't intended for that.